# Is seek_ptr unique per file?

Tags: c++, linux, file, unix

Sorry but I didn't find clear answer to my question,

I know that each file has its own seek_ptr, let's suppose the main process opened connection to file_A then before doing anything called fork()

Then forked process reads 2 chars, which is correct?

1. will seek_ptr be equal to 2 for both files?
2. seek_ptr be equal to 2 for the child process and still 0 for main process?

---

**Only if the answer is 1:**

How can I open 2 files in notepad and each file has its indicator/cursor in different locations?

Comment: It is unique *per file descriptor.* If you have the same file open twice in a single process you have two pointers. But as you have inherited the *same* file descriptor in the child process, both processes share it, and the pointer too.

Comment: And of course this isn't an issue in Windows since Windows doesn't give a fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix, `(pid, fd)` acts as a pointer into the kernel's table of open file descriptions. When a process is forked, the child process will have a different PID, call it `pid2`. So `(pid2, fd)` is a different key from `(pid, fd)`. However, these two pointers actually point to the same open file description: `fork` does not fork the open file descriptions themselves. Therefore, they share a single offset. If one process seeks, it affects the other process as well. If one process reads, it affects the other process as well.

However, either process is free to call `close` to dissociate `fd` from the existing open file description, then call `open` to create a *new* open file description which may refer to the same file. After this is done, the two processes will have different open file descriptions, and seeking in one does not affect the other.

Each successful call to `open` always creates a new open file description.

Comment: "After this is done, the two processes will have different open file descriptions, and seeking in one does not affect the other." I am confused, since they both pointing to same file (thus same file description) why don't they always share same seek_ptr?

Comment: @daniel Each open file description has its own separate offset. There can be multiple distinct open file descriptions for the same file.

Comment: So the same file can have multiple file descriptions? that sounds a little bit strange to me since  file description holds content of file too and one file can have one content....

Comment: @daniel The open file description doesn't contain the content of the file. The open file description is something in kernel memory that is created when a process opens a file. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195057/what-is-an-open-file-description

Comment: ok but u said: "However, either process is free to call close to dissociate fd from the existing open file description, then call open" does he really need to do close before? can't the process open file twice before class?

Comment: @daniel I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "open file twice before class".

Comment: can't I call open() twice for same file in same process or I need to close() one before calling 2nd open()?

Comment: @daniel You can call `open` multiple times for the same file in the same process. You don't have to close first. However, if a file descriptor is no longer useful to your process (because you don't like the fact that it shares an offset with another file descriptor in a different process) then you should close it.